No Activity found to handle Intent { act=com.google.zxing.client.android.ENCODE (zxing)
FATAL EXCEPTION: main (Ask Gemini) Process: com.android.qrscanner, PID: 19642 android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=com.google.zxing.client.android.ENCODE flg=0x80000 pkg=com.google.zxing.client.android (has extras) } at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:2075) at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1731) at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:5405) at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:5363) at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:5749) at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:5702) at com.google.zxing.client.android.share.ShareActivity.launchSearch(ShareActivity.java:109) at com.google.zxing.client.android.share.ShareActivity.access$000(ShareActivity.java:44) at com.google.zxing.client.android.share.ShareActivity$5.onKey(ShareActivity.java:98) at android.view.View.dispatchKeyEvent(View.java:14301) at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1979) at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1979) at android.widget.ScrollView.dispatchKeyEvent(ScrollView.java:491) at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1979) at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1979) at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1979) at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.superDispatchKeyEvent(DecorView.java:496) at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.superDispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1865) at android.app.Activity.dispatchKeyEvent(Activity.java:4170) at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.dispatchKeyEvent(DecorView.java:410) at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processKeyEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:6111) at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:5979) at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:5470) at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:5527) at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:5493) at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:5645) at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:5501) at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:5702) at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:5474) at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:5527) at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:5493) at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:5501) at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:5474) at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:8302) at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:8253) at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:8213) at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewRootHandler.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:5235) at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:236) at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7876) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:656) at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:967) 
how to fix this exception ,
I introduced the zxing Android project into the app, but this page cannot be opened
Modify the activity attribute in manifest
